# How can I speed up boot time?

Tags: 11.10, boot, time

Here is my [bootchart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZHEm.png) (WARNING! Huge image!)

Here is my [kernel log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/787796/)

Here is my [syslog](http://paste.ubuntu.com/787798/)

Here is my [dmesg](http://paste.ubuntu.com/787799/)

Answer (score 1):

Suspend to RAM, and wake up.

Use a electricity measuring tool, to estimate the cost of, for example, one year of such behaviour. If it is acceptable, I guess no other method will beat it. If it is not acceptable, you have to name tradeoffs and prices you're willing to pay (for SSD - not for me ;) ).

Comment: yes, although I would prefer hibernation since it's more similar to shutting down.  But then again, that requires disk I/O too :)

Answer (score 1):

Considering your boot time is mainly consumed by disk I/O, I would guess buying a faster disk would help a lot, e.g. 7200 rpm or SSD.

Answer (score 1):

Providing enough space for swap may reduce the boot time

Comment: How to do this? (I recommend expanding this answer.)

Answer (score 1):

Installing [preload](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/preload) [image: Install preload] helped me. Can be found in the Software Center.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using all cores with CONCURRENCY setting to shell? Not sure if has any effect when waking up from suspended state.
For startup, removing items like ubuntu one and others made a little difference for me. Disabling visual effects also does some good with kompiz taking lesser cpu. All of these and others consolidated here -
http://www.skipser.com/p/2/p/speed-up-ubuntu.html

Comment: CONCURRENCY=shell is now deprecated. See the comments at the top of `/etc/init.d/rc`. It actually defaults to the best possible value now.